# make ForEach final with CodeModel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I am using `com.sun.codemodel` to generate some java entity objects

i want to generate a for loop as follows:-

```
for (final Field field : classFields) {}
```

However i can only manage this

```
for (Field field : classFields) {}
```

is it possible to add `final` within a ForEach generated statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to add the `final` modifier here, because the foreach-loop in Java is just syntactic sugar. Internally the Java Iterator is used. Due to this you can not assign another `Field` Object to the variable of the foreach-loop, which makes it already `final`. You can only modify it's interal state via it's setter methods. For mor details [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) might be helpful.

Comment: correct, i dont HAVE to use final modifier, however i would like to... and codeModle doesnt seem to allow it

Comment: it makes no sense to use it and this is (in my opinion) the reason why the compiler and the codeModel does not allow you to use it